If only the virtual destructor is declared as default, Is the copy constructor implicitly generated?
In the case of the example below
Implicitly, the move constructor and move assignment operator are not created. I knew.
So, are the copy constructor and copy assignment operator generated?
Is the undefined copy constructor created implicitly?
class X
{
  public:
    virtual ~X() = default; 
}


The links I referenced are below:

Implicitly-generated constructors with explicit declaration of destructor
Does a default virtual destructor prevent compiler-generated move operations?


Deleted copy constructor - this answers your question.

Also: Diagnostics - Restore -Wdeprecated warning when user-declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted (PR45634)


are the copy constructor generated?

The copy ctor is to be defaulted but it is now deprecated from class.copy.ctor#6. Clang also gives warning for the same. You might want to explicitly default the copy ctor like X(const X&) = default; to show the intention and prepare for future removal.

If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a non-explicit one is declared implicitly.
If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defaulted ([dcl.fct.def]).
The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor ([depr.impldec]).

(emphasis mine)
And since you do have a user-declared destructor, this is deprecated.
Similarly copy assignment operator for a class with nothing but a user-declared dtor is also deprecated . From class.copy.assign#2:

If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly.
If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defaulted ([dcl.fct.def]).
The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor ([depr.impldec]).


Does saying that it is no longer used mean the same thing as saying that it is not being created?

@tuxNeoh It means that the copy ctor is deleted. Note that deleted functions do still take part in overload resolution. Also, you can use the flag -Wdeprecated-copy-ctor with gcc to warn you about this. Demo

Thanks for your help in understanding

Short answer:
=defaulting a destructor has the same effect on those as any other user-declared destructor (any destructor not implicitly generated by the compiler).
Move operations disappear, while copy operations are left in place, and the latter is deprecated (they should disappear as well).
